# Firebase https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect return code 204

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i try to calling the google analytic api but it return 204 no content. Below is the example curl and the image response from api.

curl --location 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?firebase_app_id=<firebase_app_id>&api_secret=<api_secret>' 
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' 
--data '{"app_instance_id":"298bf7539cc24651cfe40165dad9faae","events":[{"name":"tutorial_begin","params":{}}]}'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y46xc.png

May i know why this happen?
Have any other method we can know the event sent successfully?
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

204 means No Content success. So your Request was successfully received and processed by google.

Also the docs for Google Analytics Measurement Protocol states that `The Measurement Protocol always returns a 2xx status code if the HTTP request was received.` , See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=firebase#response_codes

It looks like you should verify the events that you are sending: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/validating-events?client_type=firebase#overview

and verify your implementation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/verify-implementation?client_type=firebase